# Symfony2 - array to string conversion error

Tags: forms, symfony, roles

I've read the other subjects but it doesn't solve my problem so:

I've got this

```
->add('role', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'I am:',
                'mapped' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices' => array(
                    'ROLE_NORMAL' => 'Standard',
                    'ROLE_VIP' => 'VIP',
                ) 
            ))
```

And whatever I do, I get this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony  \src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php line 458
```

In my form type the setRole method is not even called (when I rename it to some garbage the error still occurs). Why is this happening?

// EDIT

Full stack trace:

```
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php at line 458  -

     */
    protected function fixIndex($index)
    {
        if (is_bool($index) || (string) (int) $index === (string) $index) {
            return (int) $index;
        }

    at ErrorHandler ->handle ('8', 'Array to string conversion', 'C:\xampp\htdocs     \xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php', '458', array('index' => array()))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php at line 458  +
at ChoiceList ->fixIndex (array())
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php at line 476  +
at ChoiceList ->fixIndices (array(array()))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList.php at line 152  +
at SimpleChoiceList ->fixChoices (array(array()))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php at line 204  +
at ChoiceList ->getIndicesForChoices (array(array()))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToBooleanArrayTransformer.php at line 63  +
at ChoiceToBooleanArrayTransformer ->transform (array())
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 1019  +
at Form ->normToView (array())
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 332  +
at Form ->setData (array())
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper.php at line 59  +
at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForms (object(User), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 375  +
at Form ->setData (object(User))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController.php at line 49  +
at RegistrationController ->registerAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(RegistrationController), 'registerAction'), array(object(Request)))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2770  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2744  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2874  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2175  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\web\app_dev.php at line 29  +
```

Comment: please provide the full stack trace - otherwise nobody can see where the error has it's real source

Comment: Full stack trace has been provided

Comment: By the way it happens only when I set mapped to true (which is now)

Comment: mapped true is the default value - you could ommit it. it's only necessary to put it to false if you don't want to add the values to the underlying entity of the form.

Comment: what happens if you ommit "mapped" ?

Comment: I know it's not necessary but it put it there just to set it to false (to check if the errors still appears). So how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Exactly the same error as showed above

Comment: could you add your entity please?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Symfony's trying to convert your $role(array property) to *not multiple* choice field(string).

There's several ways to deal with this problem:

1. Set ***multiple*** to ***true*** in your choice form widget.
2. Change mapping from ***array*** to ***string*** for *$role* property in your entity.
3. If you insist to have above options unchanged, you can create DataTransformer. 
   **That's not the best solution because you *will* lose data if your array have more than 1 element**.

Example:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class StringToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Transforms an array to a string. 
     * POSSIBLE LOSS OF DATA
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($array)
    {
        return $array[0];
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string to an array.
     *
     * @param  string $string
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        return array($string);
    }
}
```

And then in your form class:

```
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\DataTransformer\StringToArrayTransformer;
/* ... */
$transformer = new StringToArrayTransformer();
$builder->add($builder->create('role', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'I am:',
                'mapped' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices' => array(
                    'ROLE_NORMAL' => 'Standard',
                    'ROLE_VIP' => 'VIP',
                )
              ))->addModelTransformer($transformer));
```

You can read more about DataTransformers here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: I will when I get enough reputation, for sure

Comment: It might be worth noting that this answer works specifically on an array. If the form is referencing an object (eg. a User object as was my case), the transformer needs to reference from the User object. For example, in the transformer I used $user->getRoles()[0] in the "transform" function.

Comment: Your solution is true. However, it does not make sense. If your solution is based on losing data, it is not acceptable. @user2394156 You need only little bit change on your ORM file. Make sure that your field is array or json_array. So on, Symfony2 will insert your data as serialized or json data to database column.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you use proper data type in ORM file. In this case, your role field cannot be string. It must be a many-to-many relation, array or json_array.

If you choose one of them, symfony will insert the data without effort or any type of transformer.

E.g.:

```
// Resources/config/User.orm.yml
fields:
  role:
      type: array
      nullable: false
```

So, it will live in your database as like:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"user";i:1;s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just add a DataTransformer without changing the array type of my roles attribute then I put this in my UserType :

```
use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\StringToArrayTransformer;

//...

$transformer = new StringToArrayTransformer();    
$builder->get('roles')->addModelTransformer($transformer);
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have your problem .. I solved this with this solution. I hope it helps you

this code work's on login and register form ...

user entity

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $roles ;

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
         var_dump($roles);
        if ($roles != NULL) {
            return explode(" ",$roles);
        }else {
           return $this->roles;
        }
    }


  public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }
```

UserType

```
 ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'value' => $options[0]['roles'],
                'required' => false,
            ),
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true, // render check-boxes
            'choices' => [
                'admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'user' => 'ROLE_USER',
            ]
        ))
```