# choice field symfony "Notice: Array to string conversion "

Tags: symfony

Trying to validate a choice field (multiple checkboxes) Im having this problem:

```
"Notice: Array to string conversion "
```

My validation file looks like this one:

```
Cgboard\AppBundle\Forms\UploadImageEntity:
  properties:
    image:
          ... 
    cgnetworks:
      - Choice:
          choices: [flickr, tumblr]  //<--- this is giving me problems!!!
```

My form entity class (Im not going to save this to db for now):

```
class UploadImageEntity {
    public $image;
    public $cgnetworks;
}
```

And my form class:

```
class UploadImageForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image', 'file')
            ->add('cgnetworks', 'choice', [
                    'choices'  => $this->getCgNetworks(),
                    'multiple' => TRUE,
                    'expanded' => TRUE
                ]
            );
    }

    public function getCgNetworks()
    {
        return [
        'tumblr' => 'Tumblr',
        'flickr' => 'Flickr'
        ];
    } 

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: It looks like you have a two dimensional array there, with 'Choice' being the index for the first key, and 'choices' being the second.

Comment: yes, but in the doc seems to be fine...
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: Best guess: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7759.  This might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314996/symfony2-array-to-string-conversion-error

Comment: I already read that, thanks anyway, but they use the entity trying to save in the db, I don't want to save anything for now, just validate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps you need to specify multiple in your validation

```
cgnetworks:
  - Choice:
      choices: [flickr, tumblr]  //<--- this is giving me problems!!!
      multiple: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Entity field getter. If you have something else instead of

```
public function getValue(){
      return $this->value;
}
```

You can reach this error.

Form builder uses get and set entity methods, that's why you need to return an allowable value.