# Symfony 2, CRUD is not working. Which version of Symfony is the best to use?

Tags: php, symfony, crud

I am not able to use CRUD generate with Symfony. I believe this most probably depends on Symfony version. Which version of Symfony is the best to use?

Today i have updated Symfony:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog>php symfony self-update
```

I have got the message : updating Symfony Installer to 1.4.0

Later i have made a new project:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2>php symfony new proj2 lts
```

// lts means long term support
And have got a message:
OK  Symfony 2.8.0 was successfully installed. Now you can:
   * Change your current directory to C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\prj2
   * Configure your application in app/config/parameters.yml file.
   * Run your application:
       1. Execute the php app/console server:run command.
       2. Browse to the http://localhost:8000 URL.
   * Read the documentation at http://symfony.com/doc

After generating entities i have got problems with crud.

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2>php app/console doctrine:generate:crud MeetingBundle:User
The Entity shortcut name [MeetingBundle:User]:
Do you want to generate the "write" actions [no]? Yes
Configuration format (yml, xml, php, or annotation) [annotation]:
Routes prefix [/user]:
```

Although crud generates controller and views (the latter are generated not in the bundle/resources/views, but in app/resources/views), but crud does not generate forms, thus i can not create/update/view/delete user or other entities!

I believe it depends only on Symfony version. Thus which version is the best to use?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which Symfony version generates forms for crud.

But in my case i just created custom form:
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2\src\MeetingBundle\Form\UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('phone')
           // ->add('roles') 
       /* ERROR: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
  ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13. 
                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314996/symfony2-array-to-string-conversion-error
                */
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('events')
                // createdAt
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MeetingBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'meetingbundle_user';
    }
}
```

And used it from Controller:
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\UserController.php

```
...
use MeetingBundle\Form\UserType;
....
class UserController extends Controller {
...
    public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
    {
...
        $editForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
```

Answer (score 0):

using command:

```
>php app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

Symfony version 2.7.7 and Symfony version 2.3.35 - generates Entity views in src/Namespace/Bundle/Resources/views/EntityName folder. It also generates controller and folder Form with file EntitnyNameType.php. Crud is fully functioning.

Symfony version 2.8.0 (Long term support) - generates views for entity in app/Resources/views/EntitnyName folder and also generates controller. It does not generate Form, thus CRUD is not working.

p.s.
To check which Symfony version you use:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\star>php app/console --version
```

To user certain version of Symfony for your project you have to tell this during the project creation:

```
$ symfony new my_project_name 2.6
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

If anyone can give more information about which Symfony version is better, please let me to know.